# colnames with # or % signs - R

Tags: r

I want to create an empty dataframe for missing values, like:

```
df_miss <- data.frame(
  Variable = character(),
  dtype = character(),
  NA_n = numeric(),
  NA_p = numeric(),
  Un_Ct = character()
)
```

However, I need that `NA_n` is called `#NA` and `NA_p` called `%NA`. Is this possible?

My final objective is to create a dataframe (`df_miss`) with information about missing values. I'm going to loop through the main dataframe (`df`) with:

```
x <- NULL
for (i in 1:ncol(df)){
  x <- data.frame(
    Variable = colnames(df)[i],
    dtype = class(df[,i]),
    NA_n = sum(is.na(df[,i])),
    NA_p = round(sum(is.na(df[,i]))/dim(df)[1]*100,2),
    Un_Ct = paste(unique(df[,i]), collapse=";"))
  df_miss <- rbind(df_miss,x)
}
```

This loop works perfectly. But It doens't work if I change `NA_n` and `NA_p` with `#NA` and `%NA` respectively.

Comment: Try wtih `check.names = FALSE` along with backquote on the names

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unusual column names are appended with `X` while removing certain characters as `data.frame` checks the column names with `check.names = TRUE` by default.  By making it `FALSE` and backquoting the special names, it is possible

```
df_miss <- data.frame(
   Variable = character(),
   dtype = character(),
   `#NA` = numeric(),
   `%NA` = numeric(),
   Un_Ct = character(), check.names = FALSE
 )

names(df_miss)
#[1] "Variable" "dtype"    "#NA"      "%NA"      "Un_Ct"
```

Comment: But after how can I add a value in that variable?. In the loop code, I can't just replace the NA_n with #NA because it's a comment.

Comment: Same way. Use backticks.